# Gracenote Entourage SDK iOS - Video lookup for french TV doesn't return any match

Tags: ios, video, gracenote, entourage

I've downloaded Entourage SDK for iOS v2.4.1.4018 today and tested the sample app.
Video lookup doesn't return any match for french TV channels (tested on "France 2", "D8", "CANAL +"). It used to work in the past.

I've tested with a video from foxnews and it returned some matches.

Isn't there a probleme with french channels?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we do not support audio ACR on French TV channels.

Comment: I'm surprised with your answer. In the past I was able to do ACR on French TV channels. Did you stopped this support ?? In this list: https://developer.gracenote.com/entourage-channel-listings french channels are listed as "Active"

Comment: Yes, Gracenote now does not support Franch TV channels. And thanks for pointing out, this list need to be updated.